# Automatically populate cell in Google Sheets when another cell in same row is manually filled, but also allow manual population of cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the following formula to populate a cell's value based on what is manually entered in another cell.

={"";Arrayformula(If(F3:F="",,iferror(vlookup(F3:F,Criteria!A2:B,2,0),"No Data")))}

I use that formula in the top cell and it automatically fills in all the other cells in the column. The only problem is when I enter something manually into that cell, it causes an error and none of the values for that column are displayed. Is there any way to alter the formula to allow for manual input as well as the auto input?

I'm not really sure where to begin so any help would be appreciated.